# How to add redis client for caching in GraphQL resolver

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, graphql, amazon-elasticache

Any idea how we can write graphQL resolver so that I can cache API response in the redis and on the next call it takes data from the redis instead of hitting the backend API response ?

Here user name is unique in the API. i.e. 1. getify and 2. bradtraversy

```js
/// Middleware Function to Check Cache
checkCache = (username) => {
  redis.get(username, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("====111111111111==========");
      console.log(err);

    }
    if (data !== null) {
      personInfo = data;
      // console.log(data);
      console.log("============222222222222=========");
      return personInfo;
    } 
  });
};

// Running Code 
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
   getPerson: async (_, { username }) => {
      await checkCache(username);
      console.log(username);
      if(null != personInfo) {
        console.log("=======333333333=======")
        console.log(personInfo);
        return JSON.parse(personInfo);
      }
      else {
        console.log("Fetching Data from API")
        console.log(username);
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`).then(response => response.json());
        redis.SETEX(username, 300, JSON.stringify(response)); 
        // console.log(response);
        return response;
      }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like [Apollo's Data Sources](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/), assuming you are getting data from other REST APIs. They have [a section specifically about using Redis/memcached as a cache](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/#using-memcachedredis-as-a-cache-storage-backend) instead of an in-memory one.

So the gist of this answer is, if you're using Apollo Server and wanting to cache responses from REST APIs, you can use Data Sources with [apollo-server-cache-redis](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-cache-redis)

Comment: Thanks for the reply here I am using graphQL and caching the API's on the basis of Key which is the user.  {
 getPerson(username: "getify"){
  login
  id
  name
  node_id
  avatar_url
  email
  url
  followers
  following
  followers_url
  public_gists
} 
}

Comment: Can someone help me on this ?